# React Hooks and the use of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I have a component with some states. What is the different between

Example 1:

```
function CompA() {
  [a, setA] = useState(0);
  [b, setB] = useState("Test");
  return (<div>{{ a }} and {{ b }}</div>);
}
```

and Example 2:

```
function CompA() {
  [state, setState] = useState({a: 0, b: "Test"});
  return (<div>{{ state.a }} and {{ state.b }}</div>);
}
```

Example 2 is more verbose. But all the *hooks* example I see on the internet prefer the Example 2's style. Is there any performance penalty or best practice that preferred one or another??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches will end up with the same end goal, whereby you will create a component that renders the following element: `<div>{{ state.a }} and {{ state.b }}</div>`

However, here's a scenario for **Example 1**. If you wish to update both states(`a`, and `b`) , you will have to call 2 different methods to update the state:

```
setA(1);
setB('bbbb');
```

On the other hand, for **Example 2**, you will only need to call 1 method to update the state.

```
setState({
  a: 1,
  b: 'bbb',
});
```

However, the downside of this approach is that, you will have to spread the entire state object if you only wish to update only one of the properties (credit goes to [@DrewReese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) for pointing this out). For instance, if you want to update only `b`,

```
setState({
  ...state, 
  b: 'bbb',
});
```

That being said, it will not be accurate to state that Example 1 is less "performant", as React will batch the updates if they are called within the same event handler, and cause a single re-render.

Comment: Should mention the downside to Example 2 however is if you **only** want to update `a` or `b` you have to keep spreading in all of your previous state because `useState` hook doesn't merge state updates unlike `setState` from class-based components.