# Should I consolidate key/value pairs into a single useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-functional-component

Which one is best practice in most cases?

For example:

```
const [currentDaypart, setCurrentDaypart] = useState({})
const [nextDaypart, setNextDaypart] = useState({})
```

or

```
const [daypart, setDaypart] = useState({
    current: {},
    next: {}
})
```

????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks and the use of useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098190/react-hooks-and-the-use-of-usestate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is better. Generally, you should watch out for deeply nested objects in React state. To avoid unexpected behavior, the state should be updated immutably.

Once you deep clone the state, React will recalculate and re-render everything that depends on the variables, even though they haven't changed! You flatten the state first. As soon as you do that, you will find beautiful tools that will help dealing with large states, such as useReducer().

Comment: I would say this depends on the use case. If these two values change at the same time in most cases, it would make more sense to combine them since that will reduce number of state updates and can potentially reduce number of rerenders.

Comment: @michael Thank you! I feel this helped clear up what I was asking.

Comment: @sidecus That makes sense too especially if they're changed simultaneously a majority of the time. In my case, I'll need the best of both worlds; changing singularly and multiple values at once.

Comment: @sidecus The setState() method does not immediately update the state of the component, it just puts the update in a queue to be processed later. React may batch multiple update requests together to make rendering more efficient.

Comment: Yes Michael React might batch it, and it might get batched in orders we cannot directly control - so worst case scenario you might get two rerenders.